# Regex to match a number with something or nothing

Tags: java, regex

I must match a string that can come up in 3 ways(numbers are variable and only for example illustration).

```
1-100 of 
1-25 of 
<nothing>
```

So I need a Regex that matches strings like "1-100 of ", "1-25 of " or nothing.

How could I accomplish this with a regex?
Thank you very much!

Comment: `\d+ results` will be enough to get the "x results" string

Comment: as an alternative, you could replace `\\d+-\\d+\\s+of\\s+`

Comment: I realised that I had written my question in a confusing way. I have rephrased it to try to better illustrate what I need. Thanks and sorry about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach would be anchoring the expression to the end of string:

```
(\d+) results$
```

---

For the updated question: you'd still use an anchor, but now, you'll use it on both sides:

```
^((?:.+) )?\d+ results$
```

The result will get stored in the `$1` matched group.

Comment: I realised that I had written my question in a confusing way. I have rephrased it to try to better illustrate what I need. Thanks and sorry about that!